# refund error using afterpay payment gateway

Tags: magento-1.9

I used afterpay payment gateway test mode. when i refund my amount by magento admin i get an error:

```
Afterpay API Error: Not Found
```

Please help me what is this. I didn't get the reason behind this error.

I got this error in my afterpay.log:

```
2017-12-14T09:45:17+00:00 DEBUG (7): CRON JOB - fetchPendingPaymentOrdersInfo ...
```

Thanks.